# MS Excel: Formatting numbers with a custom format and make them comparable/rankable

Tags: excel, time, number-formatting

A couple of friends of mine and I are speed-runners and we want to create an excel sheet to compare our best times for certain tasks. I want to use conditional cell formatting to mark the best time in green, the worst time in red etc.

Basically, i want to be able to input times with a custom format into the cells and let some function rank the times per row and use the results to highlight the cells.

The format i wanna use could be depicted as this: **[mm:]ss.00**
The requirements are as follows:

- seconds **must** be provided
- centiseconds **can** be provided, or they default to 00
- minutes **can** be provided. If they're used, a colon (:) is used to separate minutes and seconds

Examples:

- If I input **40**, it shows **40.00** for 40 seconds
- If I input **40.99**, it shows **40.99** for 40 seconds and 99 centiseconds
- If I input **1:04.50**, it shows **1:04.50** for 1 minute, 4 seconds and 50 centiseconds

In the following rows (Data in A2:A4), the numbers should be rankable from lowest to highest as shown.

Task 1: 17.51 | 17.70 | 18.56
`=RANK(A2; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 1
`=RANK(A3; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 2
`=RANK(A4; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 3

Task 2: 59.70 | 1:00.25 | 1:02.48
`=RANK(A2; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 1
`=RANK(A3; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 2
`=RANK(A4; A2:A4; TRUE)` should return 3

What I've tried so far:

- Custom number format: **mm:ss.00** -> Accepts the required formats, but does not rank them correctly. It detects 1:00.25 as a lower time than 59.70
- Custom number format: **[mm:]ss.00** -> Not accepted because of syntax errors

Is there a way to solve it by custom number formatting or do I need to program a macro for it ?
This problem occurred multiple times for me already, I always ended up using some workaround that cut some of the requirements, so I'd be glad to finally find a suitable solution for this.

Any help appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it just by changing the formatting because this doesn't change what is stored in the cell: as soon as you type 40 (say), it takes it as 40 days, not 40 seconds because dates and times are stored as whole numbers (for days) and fractions (for hours, minutes and seconds).

So you might need a piece of code like this to convert any times where minutes aren't specified into seconds:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Set the values to be in seconds if no minutes specified
    If Target.Value >= 1 Then
        Target.Value = Target.Value / 86400
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Format the cells you are using as time and insert the code by going to the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and double-clicking on the sheet you are using in the left-hand pane.

You don't have to restrict the range to A1:A10, but this might be good for testing purposes.